# Log out from all devices

Tags: discussion, support

I have logged in stackoverflow.com from multiple computers. Now same computers are being used by other persons. How can I log out from all of them?

Comment: Changing your password is [not enough](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94904/should-changing-your-password-invalidate-all-existing-logins)

Comment: On MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/log-out-of-all-stack-exchange-sites-with-linked-account-simultaneously